# NestJs with Fastify doesn't execute code after app.listen()

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, nestjs-fastify

this is my first question here, so i'd like to apologize in advance if i miss something important.

So this is pretty basic, but i didn't find an answer anywhere, as the title states, my NestJs application running with Fastify, simply does not execute any code after the app.listen('port') line, this doesn't happen with Express. OBS: I'm referring to the main.ts file.

relevant code below:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter({ logger: { level: 'warn' } }),
  );

  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  await app.listen(configService.get<number>(ENV_KEYS.PORT), '0.0.0.0');

  console.log(
    `Application is running on: ${await app.getUrl()}\nApplication Version: ${version}`,
  );
}
bootstrap();
```

The `console.log()` after `await app.listen` never executes, even if the app is working normally, and as far as my tests show, no code after `await app.listen()` ever executes.

I'd like to know how to overcome this issue, because i need to run some code after the app is already bootstrapped.

Comment: maybe https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/7572

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually it was not exaclty the same issue, but it got me on the tracks to find it! Since it does not happen with Express i didn't realized that i was "declaring" the same controllers twice. I'm going to reply my question with the steps i dit to fix it, thanks again @Micael Levi .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to @Micael Levi pointing me to an issue on github (github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/7572) i started to look into problems within my controllers, and the reason to freeze the application on `app.listen()` was because of "an double instance" of my AuthController, let me explain

I had my AuthController defined on AuthModule:

```
// auth.module.ts
@Module({
    imports: [
        PassportModule,
        JwtModule.register({
            secret: JWT_CONSTANTS.SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    controllers: [AuthController],
    providers: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
    exports: [AuthService, LocalStrategy, JwtStrategy],
})
```

And in the AppModule, i was importing AuthModule while also declaring AuthController AGAIN:

```
// app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(getConfigServiceConfiguration()),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) =>
        getDatabaseModuleOptionsAsync(configService),
      inject: [ConfigService],
    }),
    AuthModule, // <-AuthController is declared within AuthModule scope
    UsuarioModule,
    ClienteModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController, AuthController] // <- AuthController here again,
  providers: [AppService],
})
```

Removing AuthController from `controllers:[]` in AppModule solved my problem. Rookie mistake, but for some reason this isn't a problem with express, and doesn't raise any compilation errors with Fastify either!